# Urban Airship tags getting wiped on device registration

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com

So, we are using Urban Airship for our push messaging API in iOS/android. In iOS, when the app is opened we register it with urban airship using this method in our app delegate.

```
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];

// You can also programmatically override the plist values:
// config.developmentAppKey = @"YourKey";
// etc.

// Call takeOff (which creates the UAirship singleton)
[UAirship takeOff:config];
// Request a custom set of notification types
[UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability);
// This will trigger the proper registration or de-registration code in the library.
[[UAPush shared] setPushEnabled:YES];
```

What we are having trouble with is that whenever a device logs in for the second time, it seems to wipe the tags we have created using our own back end tools on urban airship. Does anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1292457-what-you-need-to-know-when-setting-tags-from-your-server-for-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the article that @dperconti mentioned in comment on UA's support website:

```
[UAPush shared].deviceTagsEnabled=NO;
```

should be called before you call

```
[UAirship takeOff:config];
```

in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of your app delegate. Thanks for this find, UA's support website can be tricky to find answers on, and emailing did not help.